# split kendo inline editing component in react and sending parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui

Im using kendo-ui grid with react using this example

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing/

how can i separate

```js
class MyCommandCell extends GridCell {
```

from the parent component so I can reuse the component , and how can i send parameters to the component?

tried to do it , but the straight forward  way did not worked

Comment: The demo link you have posted already answers your question, since the demo was updated yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a react [Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) into separate file like:

```
export default function MyCommandCell(enterEdit, remove, save, cancel, editField) {
return class extends GridCell {
    render() {
        return !this.props.dataItem[editField]
            ? (
                <td>
                   <button onClick={(e) => enterEdit(this.props.dataItem)}> Edit
                   </button> 
                </td>
            );
    }
}
};
```

Then you can reuse it in multiple places by importing it from your file like:

```
import MyCommandCell from './my-command-cell.jsx';
```

And call the HOC with the external parameters you need to pass to the Cell:

```
this.CommandCell = MyCommandCell(enterEdit,remove,save,cancel, "inEdit");
```